# Can the value of a dictionary redirect to another dictionary in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, variables

I'm trying to make a sort of black-room game where you have to use ZQSD to move. I want to get my variable to get the value of the dictionary I just got in. The name of a dictionary is the name of the room, the keys are ZQSD for moving and the value a new room. So I want this value of the new room I'm in to be the new "place" variable. How can I do that?

```
A2 = {"D": "B2"}
B2 = {"D":"C2","Q":"A2","S":"B3"}
C1 = {"S":"C2"}

place = A2
while True:
   x = input().upper()
   if x in place:
       print("you moved to another room")
       place = place[x]
   else:
       print("there is a wall in this direction")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary to hold the dictionaries. `{"D": "B2"}` has no idea that the name `A2` happens to reference it.

```
data = {"A2": {"D": "B2"},
        "B2": {"D": "C2","Q": "A2","S": "B3"},
        "C1": {"S": "C2"}}

starting = data["A2"]
move = "D"
new_place = data[starting[move]]
print(new_place)
# {'D': 'C2', 'Q': 'A2', 'S': 'B3'}
```

Use `KeyError`s to understand if there is a missing key/move (= a wall).